# Running multiple containers of the same image in a pod versus running multiple pods versus running on multiple nodes

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I have a rather classic web app that I'm running on OpenShift/Kubernetes, it consists of a web page container and a database container. I'm looking now at some options for scaling and I'm trying to understand the differences with these 3 scenarios:

1. Run multiple instances of the web container next to a single instance of the database container inside a single pod on a single node
2. Run multiple pods with 1 instance of the web container, one pod with a single instance of the database container on a single node (using some affinity)
3. Same as 2 but on multiple nodes (using some anti-affinity)

How does each scenario affect things like resource consumption and network overhead, and how well does each one allow you to scale up?
Are there options I haven't considered that might be valid as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can skip scenario 1 because that's not how things are done with Kubernetes. Generally, you run one container per Pod, except for tightly coupled sidecar containers that might run along with the main container in the same Pod.

Scenarios 2 and 3 are the correct way to do things with Kubernetes. You have a separate [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#deployment-v1-apps) for the web app and for the database (the database might run as a [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#statefulset-v1-apps)) each consisting of a variable number of Pods. Each Pod contains one container of the corresponding application. This allows you to scale both tiers (the web app and the database) independently from each other.

Whether the various Pods run on the same node or on different nodes is not something that you would worry too much about, in most cases. Kubernetes is designed to do the assignments of Pods to nodes automatically and dynamically, and which node a Pod runs on is transparent to the application running in this Pod and to clients of this application. Kubernetes can also reschedule a Pod to a different node at any time.

You can, however, influence the Kubernetes scheduler decision (with [affinities and anti-affinities](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity), [node selector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector), [taints and tolerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/)). In this case, typically you would prefer the Pods of a Deployment to be spread out across multiple nodes to avoid that a node becomes a single point of failure. Restricting all Pods of an app to a single node is not common, except probably for very specific use cases in which this might be necessary.

So, in summary, scenario 3 is the way to go, and you get the distribution of Pods across nodes usually for free (by probability) but you can enforce it with [Pod anti-affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#inter-pod-affinity-and-anti-affinity).

Comment: Great summary, thank you! One small follow up, what about things like network overhead between the web container and database container when running on different nodes, say that I'm doing a lot of database calls. Running on the same node will be faster but more fragile, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, if the Pods are on different nodes, the requests are routed through the network between the nodes. So, it generates some network overhead. If the Pods are on the same node, the requests never reach the physical network, but are just routed within the node from the virtual network interface of one Pod to the virtual network interface of the other Pod. So, it's probably faster. The disadvantage is that if that node fails, you lose all your Pods.